# DocuSign_CreateEnvelope error

Tags: docusignapi

Apparently when Docusign is installed in Salesforce, it doesn't inherently grant permissions to Salesforce Community profiles. I am trying to figure out what are all permissions that are needed - objects, fields, VF page, etc. Is it documented somewhere?

"Send With Docusign" button works great as Salesforce user but when I try to use it as Salesforce Community user it throws and error, "DocuSign_CreateEnvelope is undefined". I believe this occurs because of some missing permissions. Trying to figure it out has been like finding a needle in haystack.

Comment: When you install the package, it asks you what profiles you want permissions for. Honestly the easiest way is to reinstall it and select the correct permission profiles at that point. Else check here: https://community.docusign.com/t5/DocuSign-for-Salesforce/DocuSign-Quick-Tip-DocuSign-for-Salesforce-Recommended-Salesforce/td-p/21941

Comment: Thanks Andre for the response! Actually I did reinstall the package and found that by default Docusign package permissions are not granted to Salesforce Community User Profiles even after you select all profiles during installation. I did manually granted all permissions and verified from your link that they all there. At this point I think the issue might be with user license type and not permissions. I just need someone to confirm it and a solution on how Docusign can be used with Salesforce community users. thanks!

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I have updated the Community User Profile, updated all kind of permissions, it works for my Admin user but not for Communities user. Hopefully, someone will have a good answer to this. In the meanwhile, I guess I will try the re-install :-(

Comment: DevIntern - I was able to figure out the issue. The Send with Docusign button contains "{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();"
As Community has a different domain than regular instance this doesn't work.
You will have to create a new custom button to use it in Community as follows - "{!REQUIRESCRIPT("dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")}
DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();"

Comment: I was able to figure out the issue. The Send with Docusign button contains "{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();" As Community has a different domain than regular instance this doesn't work. You will have to create a new custom button to use it in Community as follows - "{!REQUIRESCRIPT("dsfs__DocuSign_JavaScript")} DocuSign_CreateEnvelope();"